# Error when sending multiple transactions

Tags: web3js, transactions, ropsten, infura, error

I'm having a weird issue with the code below in that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. It seems more apparent when `TRANSACTIONS` is set to a larger number. I have had it fail **AND** pass with `TRANSACTIONS`set to 20. What boggles my mind is that if i set `from:` to always be `accounts[0]` it seems to work every time, even when i set `TRANSACTIONS` to 100. The error is thrown in `executePromises()` and I show the error below but it's a `Error: gas required exceeds allowance (8000029) or always failing transaction`-error. Further i have observed that, when it fails, it does send out *some* transactions that get picked up for example it sent out transactions for account 1-5 but not for the 6th or 7th etc.

Can someone shed some light on this?

```js
async function multipleTx(
  TRANSACTIONS,
  GAS_PRICE,
) {
  let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  let tripKey = 0
  var sendBlockNumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
  let bookingPromiseArr = []
  let txStartTime = Date.now()
  for (let i = 0; i < TRANSACTIONS; i++) {
    let promise = ''
    promise = instance.methods.bookTrip(tripKey).send({
      from: accounts[i],
      gasPrice: GAS_PRICE,
      value: 1,
    })
    bookingPromiseArr.push(promise)
  }
  var receipts = await executePromises(bookingPromiseArr)

  /* more code below ...*/
}

async function executePromises(promisesArr) {
  let res = await Promise.all(promisesArr)
    .then(async (receipts) => {
      return receipts
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('executePromises():', error)
      process.exit(1)
    })
  return res
}
```

Smart Contract Function

```js
    function bookTrip(uint256 key) external payable requireTrip(key) {
        Trip storage trip = trips[key];
        trip.passengers[msg.sender] = trip.price;
        trip.passengerCount++;
        emit LogNewTripPassenger(msg.sender, key, trip.price);
    }
```

Error Log:

```
executePromises(): Error: gas required exceeds allowance (8000029) or always fai
ling transaction
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules
\@truffle\hdwallet-provider\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\provi
der.js:18:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukv
aruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:96:
13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvar
uteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request-event-ta
rget.ts:44:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\ex
amensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:219:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvarutekni
k\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:345:8)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\exam
ensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:311:39)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
```

#### Update

I took the advice that @LauriPeltonen gave and stripped everything down as much as I could and looked at what @goodvibration suggested regarding mixing synchronous and asynchronous execution in an incorrect manner. I still get the same error. The code below shows `Transaction` set to 50. On etherscan I can see that my smart contract received 20 of those supposed 50 transactions. However on a second attempt it managed to send all 50.

```js
const web3 = require('./web3.js')
const DeRail = require('../../build/contracts/DeRail.json')
const address = require('../../address.json')
const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(DeRail.abi, address.address, {
  gasPrice: '20000000000',
})

async function multipleTx(TRANSACTIONS = 50, GAS_PRICE = 1000000000) {
  let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  let tripKey = 19
  console.log(accounts.length)
  let bookingPromiseArr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < TRANSACTIONS; i++) {
    let promise = instance.methods.bookTrip(tripKey).send({
      from: accounts[i],
      gasPrice: GAS_PRICE,
      value: 1,
    })
    bookingPromiseArr.push(promise)
  }
  var receipts = await executePromises(bookingPromiseArr)
  process.exit(0)
}

async function executePromises(promisesArr) {
  try {
    let res = await Promise.all(promisesArr)
    return res
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('executePromises():', error.message)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

multipleTx()
```

Comment: To me, it is pretty obvious that you are trying to execute a function which is permitted only to `accounts[0]` (probably the contract owner or something similar). Your transaction fails because the function reverts when called with any other account (not because of a gas-related issue, as might be inferred from the error-message).

Comment: That doesn't make any sense because i've called that function from other accounts than `accounts[0]`. The `requireTrip` modifier doesn't restrict the function in any way regarding who is calling it. To clearify it is my smart contract as well.

Comment: What I would do is reduce the complexity until it the failures end and then figure out what caused it. If the failures persist it has something to do with your deployment logic

Comment: What is `instance`? There is no sign of it in your code prior to using it. Is it possibly a different instance for each transaction (or for some of them)? Could there be different implementations of that function, where in some cases your `require(msg.sender == someSpecificAddress)`?

Comment: BTW, I believe that in function `executePromises`, you are mixing synchronous and asynchronous execution in an incorrect manner. Better just use one of them. For example: `try {return await Promise.all(promisesArr);} catch (error) {...}`.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen The code shown above is already reduced in complexity there's funcitonality to wait for block confirmations inside `executPromises()` but i removed it for the sake of shorter post. Nevertheless i have run the code exactly as presented in this question and i still get the same error sometimes.

Comment: @goodvibration `instance`is the contract instance i import it from a file at the top of this file. It is not possible that they are different instances and there is only one contract and one version of `bookTirp()` and there is no require statement that checks who the sender is for that function. As for if i'm mixing synchronous and asynchronous in an incorrect manner, i'm not sure. i can try your suggestion

Comment: Do you have a sufficient number of unlocked accounts listed in the `accounts` array?

Comment: @goodvibration Yes i do and they are funded adequately. I know this because sometimes all the transactions actually gets sent through

Comment: So it sounds like it might have something to do with timing, or more specifically, with how your asynchronous execution works.

Comment: @goodvibration that sounds plausable and it would explain the random behavior in all of this since it does work sometimes but not always.

Comment: @goodvibration went through everything as per yours and Lauri's suggestions i'm still having the same behavior. I can't see anything wrong with that code with regard to mixing synch and asynch or otherwise.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen i updated my post and did as u suggested to remove more complexity, but my problems still persist, what did you mean with the problem has to do with my deployment logic?

Comment: I would still suggest you to trim down your contract code. So just have a very basic function which for example only increments a state variable and does nothing else. That way you can make sure the problem is not in your contract execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem to have been entirely a problem with Infura. I suspect it is in regard to their rate limits. Nevertheless we have now set up our own ethereum node using geth and are able to isssue as many transactions as we want pretty much problem free!